# Read NURBS control points in Maya from an ASC file

Tags: maya, mayavi, mel, nurbs, pymel

Say I have an ASC file with 100 (x,y,z) coordinates (representing a helix-like world line trajectory). I want to import that file in Maya and create a NURBS with each of the coordinate from my ASC file as a control point.

I know how to import asc files in python but I don't know how to create NURBS control point out of it!

I assume it should be a simple script but I am new to MEL script and Maya driven Python. Any script snippet in MEL or Python to get it working?

Thanks!

Comment: Okay. What is your question and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I imported the asc file in Maya using Python. Now i have all these 100 coordinate points. I don't know how to create a NURBS such that my imported coordinate points are the control points of this NURBS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `curve` command takes an argument with the flag `p` (for 'points').  So a simple linear curve from 0,0,0 to 1,0,0  looks like

```
 import maya.cmds as cmds
 cmds.curve(  p=[(0,0,0), (1,0,0)],  d = 1)
```

and a degree-3 nurbs curve might look like

```
cmds.curve( p=[(0, 0, 0), (3, 5, 6), (5, 6, 7), (9, 9, 9)], d=3 )
```

Your script will have to convert the asc points to XYZ values. If you are reading these yourself from a text file you'll have to the use standard python open command to open and read from a file.  If you already have locators or other physical objects in your scene you can get their positions with the `xform` command.  This will get the position of an object named 'locator_name_goes_here' as an XYZ tuple.

```
loc_pos = cmds.xform('locator_name_goes_here', q=True, t=True, ws=True)
```

So.to run a curve through a bunch of points you would collect all of their positions in a big list and then pass that whole list to the curve command's `p` flag:

```
# assuming all locators or objects are selected in order
locator_positions = []
for each_locator in cmds.ls(sl=True):
    locator_positions.append (cmds.xform(each_locator, q=True, t=True, ws=True)
cmds.curve(p=locator_positions, d=3)
```